# Are there any way to change the authentication type to claims based in code without using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, configuration, claims-based-auth, web-application

I'm creating an application that changes the authentication type to Claims based, but I'm trying not to use powershell.
any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply change application to Claims authentication from code you can use:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://testwebapp/"));
webApp.UseClaimsAuthentication = true;
webApp.Update();
```

But my suggestion is that you use PowerShell or Central Administration to setup Claims.

Answer (score -3):

You can do the following steps:

1. Open **Central Administration**.
2. Click **Application Management** > **Manage web application**
3. Select your Web application and then click **Authentication provider**.
4. Click **Default** link and then configure your authentication.

Comment: sorry, I said in code

Comment: Also, this is not correct. You cannot currently change from classic -> claims using Central Admin. Give it a try on a VM!

Comment: I'm sorry but I saw that your title didn't include "in code" before :-). @Ben: good comment, mate ;-).